# surefile plugin maven shows zero tests

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am running a maven project and everything works fine except for code coverage reports . I am using surefire plugin and jacoco. Surefire plugin shows tests as 0 and codecoverage in jacoco report also comes with zero coverage. Please advise what to check?

Comment: Please show your pom file, how you call Maven, Show an example of your test code etc. etc. much more details needed...

Comment: sorry for late response. I got answer. its because of version mismatch

Comment: Can you write that as answer....

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with an older version of surefire plugin .